# Reducing array to average readings

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, statistics

Taking the payload below, I need to output the average of each reading.

For example the readings for key *2* are 1, 4, 7.  The average is (1+4+7)/3 = 4.

The data is formatted in multi-dimensional arrays, such that each sub-array contains pairs with a key and a reading value. For example:

```
[
  [
    [2, 1],
    [4, 2],
    [6, 3]
  ],
  [
    [2, 4],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 6]
  ],
  [
    [2, 7],
    [4, 8],
    [6, 9]
  ]
]
```

The final result should be:

```
[
[2, 4],
[4, 5],
[6, 6]
]
```

My effort so far seems to work.

```
const payload = [
  [
    [2, 1],
    [4, 2],
    [6, 3]
  ],
  [
    [2, 4],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 6]
  ],
  [
    [2, 7],
    [4, 8],
    [6, 9]
  ]
]

const result = payload.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {

    if(currentIndex === 0){
        return accumulator
    }
    return currentValue.reduce((a, c, i) => {       
        accumulator[i][1] += c[1]
        return accumulator
    }, accumulator)

 }).map((currentValue, index, array) => {
    return [currentValue[0], currentValue[1] / array.length]
})
```

Comment: Above `payload.reduce(...)` mutates the first element of `payload` - that is probably unexpected behavior and could cause bugs further on.

Comment: Thanks @le_m - It was unexpected, and did cause bugs.  A lot of head scratching yesterday until I read your comment.

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 6 → 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Average calculation issue

The example data happens to be a 3x3 matrix of values, so the calculation of the average appears to be correct. However, try using a 2x3 matrix of values (i.e. remove the 3<sup>rd</sup> sub-array of values) - it should become clear that the divisor used in the calculation of the average is incorrect.

One should divide the sum by the number of readings corresponding to each key, not the number of keys in each sub-array- i.e. divide by `payload.length` instead of `array.length` in the callback to `Array.map()`.

#### Original Array Modification

[le_m](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/134719/le-m) is correct with the statement in [the comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/181141/reducing-array-to-average-readings#comment344169_181141):

> Above `payload.reduce(...)` mutates the first element of `payload` - that is probably unexpected behavior and could cause bugs further on.

This is because the `initialValue` [parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters) of [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is omitted, which causes `payload[0]` to be used as `accumulator` the first time <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters)</sup>. This can be observed by inspecting the values of `currentIndex` in the callback - for the sample data, it starts with `1` and ends with `2`.

In order to not mutate the first element of `payload`, a deep clone of the first element can be used (e.g. with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)).

```
let initialValue = [];
if (payload.length) {
    initialValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload[0]));
}
const result = payload.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) => { 
    /*...*/ 
}, initialValue)).map((currentValue, index, array) => {
    return [currentValue[0], currentValue[1] / array.length]
});
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Sam Onela - I've ended up learning a lot from this fairly simple task. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sam’s answer including the word “matrix” got me thinking on using the `transpose` operation, resulting in a somewhat declarative solution:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/17428705/280304
const transpose = mx => mx[0].map((col, i) => mx.map(row => row[i]))

const sumSecond = (acc, [k, v]) => acc + v

transpose(payload).map(row =>
  [row[0][0], row.reduce(sumSecond, 0) / row.length])
```

(naturally, traversing and creating the arrays multiple times is going to be slower than doing everything in one go, but I feel it does bring clarity.)

...or constituting `transpose(payload)` with `zip(...payload)` where `zip = (arr, ...arrs) => arr.map((val, i) => arrs.reduce((a, arr) => [...a, arr[i]], [val]))`

from [*A simple ES6 zip function* on a Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/renaudtertrais/25fc5a2e64fe5d0e86894094c6989%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Be10).

Comment: I added the context from your comment into your answer - please see the **when should I comment section** in [Comment Everywhere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)